# Two sets of margins for a single page

Tags: indentation

Does anyone know how to change the marins of a document midpage? IE a header has .5 inch margins but the text itself has only 1 inch margins?

Comment: Can you give us an example? Is this formally a page header, or just the first block of text in the page body?

Comment: does any one know how to change the margin of the first page, different from the main body? I use \documentclass{book}

Comment: @ren [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) If you have a similar question which is not answered here, please post it as a fresh one using the "Ask Question" link above. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) like this are more than welcome! Please also include a link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the margins for small pieces of text (not spreading over more than a page, usually) using the changepage package. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{4cm}{2cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth*}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The `changepage` package has some more features for adjusting more of the textblock, but if it's the entire page that you want to change, the latest version of the geometry package provides this somewhat more conveniently. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{margin=4cm}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\lipsum
\end{document}
```